# Android application : how do I create a comment field?

Tags: android, comments, textview

Ok I'll try again..

I'm developing an Hybrid Android App. I want to add a comment field where people can share their thoughts :

For example, in my activity I have an EditText and a Button "add comment". I put my comment in the EditText and when I click on the button it will be displayed in my acitivity and added to the comments of other users and that exist (in my server for example).

My question is : Is there any Layout Widgets or Tools that I can use or should I create a TextView for each comment ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a simple [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) for doing this instead of creating a text view for each of the comment